# What is the difference between "raise" and "get up"?

Tags: meaning

When must I use **get up** and **raise** ?

Example:

> Help me to raise this table.

---

> Help me to get up this table.

Which sentence is correct ?

Comment: You might say "... get this table up", but "... get up this table" is not idiomatic, and would likely be taken as "... get up ON this table".

Comment: I guess you would hold a seance to raise a table. Or is the question about **rising** from the table vs **getting up** from the table, after a meal, say?

Comment: It would be to load the table. And I'm sorry for my bad English, I'm still studying.

Comment: '*Help me lay the table*' perhaps. Arranging plates and cutlery on the table, ready for a meal, is called laying the table. You could also say, '*Help me **to** lay the table*', but we usually leave out the 'to'.

Comment: What I mean is that: https://s2.glbimg.com/IgyhOtOQrOMIbRooTgzaMHSAg2A=/s.glbimg.com/jo/g1/f/original/2015/10/23/patricia.jpg

Comment: You mean “lift this table”, or perhaps carry it.

Comment: I’d either say, “Help me pick up this table”, or “help me carry this table”   I’d only lift the table to sweep under it or to put something under a leg to steady it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person in the picture is *lifting* the table. *Raising* a table suggests making the top higher, perhaps so as to be more comfortable for a tall person sitting at it.

You *get up* when you rise from a chair, or get out of bed in the morning. We wouldn't use it of lifting furniture.

Answer (score 1):

To raise a thing is to cause it to rise. Up is the general direction for things to rise in.
To raise the table is indeed to make it higher whether for comfort or survival or some other reason. The phrase *get up* is not used for this.

Get up as stated can be used with on or onto as in *Get the table up onto the truck*.

One may raise one's children from bed in the morning as a more formal way of getting them up.